# How to set UTF 8 in DBMS_OUTPUT in Oracle using Intellij Idea?

Tags: oracle, plsql, utf-8

I have problem with Intellij Idea DB browser. It doest show national characters in UTF 8. I have this procedure:

```
DECLARE
type name_char_array is table of nvarchar2(1) index by PLS_INTEGER;

char_array name_char_array;

name zone.name%type;
BEGIN
dbms_output.enable(1000000);
for zone_rec in (Select * from zone where name is not null)
Loop
    for i in 1 .. length(zone_rec.NAME)
    loop
        char_array(i) := substr(zone_rec.NAME, i, 1 );
    end loop;


    char_array(1) := UPPER(char_array(1));
    for i in 2..char_array.last loop
         if char_array(i - 1) = ' ' THEN
                 char_array(i) := UPPER(char_array(i));
         end if;
    end loop;

    for i in char_array.FIRST..char_array.last loop
       name := name || char_array(i);
    end loop;

    if name != zone_rec.NAME THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Id: ' || zone_rec.ID || ' Name:' || name);
    end if;

    char_array.DELETE();
    name := null;


End Loop;

END;
```

and DBMS output show me this:
[image]

Can someone give me a point how to show this rows correctly? I dont know what is correct locale. Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you checked this setting? Editor | General | Console | Default Encoding = UTF-8 https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/encoding.html#console

Comment: I set default encoding to UTF-8, but without any effect.